# Facebook Ads Insight CSV Export via API is showing HTML login page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

I am downloading 60 ads objects worth of Facebook Ads Insights metrics and including all the fields with a time_increment of 1 for a date range of 6 months. I then download the data in CSV file via this link

https://www.facebook.com/ads/ads_insights/export_report?report_run_id={adsReportRun.ReportRunId}&format=csv&locale=en_US&access_token={config.AccessToken}

However, occasionally, it will download HTML content. When I opened the file, it shows a Facebook login page. I am unsure what is the reason for this as the access token has ads_read and all other permissions required to read the ads insights data. The expected data was returned in a previous data download, but it will occasionally return us the HTML login page.

Comment: The docs are here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/insights/best-practices#export-reports

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be a rate limit issue as I was able to re-download it after waiting a few seconds.